# Como eu faço pra printar quantas vezes tem um termo igual numa lista python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    lista = []
    ingresso = (str(input()))
    lista.append(ingresso)
    if ingresso== "FIM":
        break
    elif ingresso != "NORMAL" and ingresso !=  "VIP" and ingresso != "FIM":
        print(f"Comando {ingresso} não existe")
```

Gente eu estou tentando fazer um programa que é pra contar o numero de ingressos um ingresso vip e outro normal se eu digitar errado alguma coisa eu tenho que digitar fim depois, até ai tudo bem, porém eu queria fazer também que aparecesse na saída quantos ingressos vips e normais foram contados eu tentei colocar numa lista e usar o count() porém só o fim que vai pra lista o fim seria para acabar as variaveis da entrada como proceder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma simples, você poderia `list comprehension`

```
normal = len([n for n in lista if n == 'NORMAL'])
vip = len([v for v in lista if n == 'VIP'])
```

Pode também usar o `Counter` da biblioteca `collections`

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(lista)
```

O `Counter` retorna um dicionário que pode ser acessado diretamente pela chave. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> print(c)
Counter({'NORMAL': 15, 'VIP': 2})

>>> print(c['NORMAL'])
15

>>> print(c['VIP'])
2
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: muito obrigado com algumas modificações consegui usar o counter no meu valeu ai ajudou demaissss :)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se interpretei seu problema direito, mas, pelo o que vejo o erro está em você dar append no ingresso antes de checar as condicionais de existência do mesmo e em você limpar a lista toda vez em que o loop while executa. No caso você deveria usar o código desta forma:

```
 lista = []
 while True:
     ingresso = (str(input()))
     if ingresso == "FIM":
         lista.append("FIM") #(Opcional)
         break
     elif ingresso != "NORMAL" and ingresso !=  "VIP" and ingresso != "FIM":
         print(f"Comando {ingresso} não existe")
         continue
     lista.append(ingresso)
```

Comment: valeu modifiquei e com as dicas do cara de cima conseguir finalizar meu codigo :)